# How-to integrate Paypal Without Web Browser?

Tags: web-services, paypal

It is possible to do this, I mean, I have a hardware environment where I have no web browser but I have a webservice and https.

Can I do it using web services only ? I mean the authorization and the realization of a completed purchase.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Paypal offers APIs:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_overview

Comment: they do offer an API, but i think, at least here in germany, you need at least 1 browser popup, for the user to login to Paypal, you're not allowed to process the users Paypal credentials in any way. what he can do, is just send a request of payment via Paypal